# How to Implement Sequence Generator in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How to Implement Sequence Generator for primary key id in Hibernate so that it can be Used in Multiple DB like Oracle, MSSQL and MySQL?

Comment: have you tried anything yet? did you run into errors?

Comment: I think portable solution to JPA primary key is different, i.e. `GenerationType.AUTO` or in this way

Comment: I tried using sequence generator directly in my model class. I get error when i run the code.

Comment: @jacez Cz - I tried that but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Sequence Generator is Oracle style, so it does not support MySql. Please post your error

Comment: The Sequence Generator is supported by Oracle, SQL Server 2012, PostgreSQL, DB2, HSQLDB according with SQL:2003 standard.

Answer (score 1):

To have a sequence generator which can be used in many DBs, its better to use **Table Generator** as it's not DB specific.

**Sequence Generator**( which uses SQL Sequence) isn't supported by various DBs.

You'll need to create a Table for maintaining sequence values.
It should contain 2 columns & a single row.
Columns are

1. Primary Key Name(`Varchar` type)
2. Next Value(`Number` type)

The single row in Table should consist a `varchar` value of any name used for identifying next value of sequence.

The syntax which you can use for Table Generator is as follows:

`@Entity
@TableGenerator(name="Your_Generator_Name",table="Your_Generator_Table_Name",pkColumnName="Primay_Key_Name",pkColumnValue="Varchar_value_in_PkColumn",valueColumnName="Next Value")
        public class MyEntityClass{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy="GenerationType.TABLE",generator="name_in_TableGenerator"
      Integer primaryId;
      //rest of code
}`

For more info refer to [this link](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/)